# How to ignore environment variables under Mac?

Tags: macos, variables, environment

hope someone can help me. I wrote an installation shell script for python and some other libraries. All the packages are installed in a selected folder. For example "~/Desktop/inst" and not under "/usr/local". The problem, if there are some environment variables set, then they could mess up the installation. Is it somehow possible to prevent that? Maybe to ignore the set environment variables. Or is there maybe an other trick?

Comment: Isn’t it the point of environment variables that they are a part of the environment? If you want variables local to your script, why not read them from a config file?

Comment: But if macports is installed then the ist the PATH=/opt/local or maybe the path to QTDIR is set or some other path are set. And I don't want to use or build against any stuff that is installed on a machine. I want only to install and use the packages from my script. Sure I can install everything to usr/local or maybe /opt/local but the point of my installation shell script is not to touch the system.

Answer (score 0):

yeah...look up for loginhook and run your script by making it the loginhook for your mac...that way when ur system logs in and no variables exist, your application should run fine as there are no variables. hope it helps. here is a link for knowing how to set an app as loginhook [here]. hope this helps
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2006081701162739

Answer (score 0):

You could use `printenv` to see what variables are set and unset them (except for the ones you want/need to keep, like PATH):

```
for var in $(printenv | sed 's/=.*//'); do
    case "$var" in
      TERM|SHELL|TMPDIR|USER|PATH|PWD|HISTCONTROL|SHLVL|HOME|LOGNAME|DISPLAY )
        : ;; # Leave these untouched
      * )
        unset "$var" ;;
    esac
done
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin # Override existing PATH with standard value
```